# Where to instantiate object?

Tags: java, oop

I have an abstract class `Products`, with two subclasses `Mouse`, `Keyboard`.

My file handler reads attributes from a database and determines which object we want to instantiate.

The subclasses first call the super class to handle validation methods common to both `mouse` and `keyboard`, then the subclass handles unique validation. I hope it does anyway, does the code continue after the `super()` call within the subclasses?

The potential issue I see with this is that I need to declare and instantiate the object within my file handler class which I assume is not ideal, as I'd want to instantiate the object within the subclasses `mouse`or `keyboard`, but Java wants me to insantiate within the file handler to call `Mouse(String attribute1, ...)`

```
abstract class Products
{
    protected String barcode;
    protected String brand;
    protected boolean wireless;
    protected int quantity;
    protected double originalCost;
    protected double retailCost;

    //Setters that are common to both mouse and keyboard objects
    protected Products(String barcode, String brand, String wireless, String quantity, String originalCost, String retailCost)
    {
        //set barcode
        if(barcode.length() == 6 && barcode.matches("^[0-9]*$"))
        {
            this.barcode = barcode;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid barcode attribute");
        }

       //ect ect for other attributes
}
```

```
public class Keyboard extends Products
{
    String productType;
    String layoutType;

    public Keyboard(String barcode, String brand, String wireless, String quantity, String originalCost, String retailCost, String productType, String layoutType)
    {
        //call super
        super(barcode, brand, wireless, quantity, originalCost, retailCost);

        //validate productType and assign values ect ect    
    }
}
```

```
    public void readFile()
    {
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            String barcode = x.next();
            String name = x.next();
            String type = x.next();
            String brand = x.next();
            String colour = x.next();
            String connectivity = x.next();
            String quantity = x.next();
            String originalCost =  x.next();
            String retailCost = x.next();
            String additionalInfo =  x.next();

            switch(name)
            {
            case "keyboard":
                Keyboard(barcode, brand, connectivity, quantity, originalCost, retailCost, type, additionalInfo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would handle the validation outside the constructor, in a static method and then call the validation and constructor from a factory method. Possibly create a separate Factory class that holds the validation logic and creation of different Product objects

Comment: You may consider using another config file like JSON to read your config file. Modern JSON libraries can directly parse stuff into a POJO.

Comment: @jaco0646 added code, with removed areas that do not concern question in mind, hope it helps

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the factory class you speak of is basically my Products class, given that Products is abstract and cannot be instantiated. Do you suggest having a static method that validates in each of the three classes, then tell the constructor to create a new object if all validation tests have been passed? This seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @maio290 unfortunetly I have been restricted to .txt for holding data, I'd have to double check if this can be done.

Comment: A txt can contain json ;)

Comment: A Factory class is something different than a base class constructor, it's a common design pattern so you should be able to find plenty of examples online.